# Gap between floating divs

Tags: css, css-float

I always wondered how to fix the gap between floating elements if they don't have the same height:

Here you can see a gap between `Featured` and `Notice` which I would like to get rid of. (Get's even larger when the screen resolution is larger since the `Featured` box becomes more stretched and thus the text spreads over less lines)
[image: float1]

Maybe important to note that this is the order of the floating left elments:

1. Featured
2. News
3. Headlines
4. Notice

Layout for smaller screens (this is looking perfectly fine I just wanted to show you what I mean in the following description with inconsistent layout based on screen resolution)
[image: float2]

If the design would be consistent I wouldn't mind implementing some kind of grid system but in my case I'm using styles based on screen resolution so at a certain screen resolution the boxes change from 50% to 100% width (no fixed value used here).

I thought that fluid girds might be the right way to go but after checking them (never used them before) they feel rather static and I'm not sure that they can solve this problem.

**EDIT:**
Sample of the broblem: http://jsfiddle.net/UfVrH/. Note the fixed height values in A-D are only there to simulate content stretching the div.

Comment: DO you have code of this screen

Comment: I will prepare something small which will show the same behavior. Give me some minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To fix such an issue you need to calculate the width and height of each element and re-arrange them by positioning them absolutely, luckily for you there is such a plugin that does this,  [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Comment: Seems like this is what I'm looking for, after working through it I will accept this as answer given it truly fixes my problem. I'm still open for pure html/css options.

Comment: @Layne still looking for someone to figure it out as [well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597956/balanced-alternating-column-layout-in-css3)